# Emails are not sending from Magento 2 on Ubuntu/Apache

Tags: magento2, send-mail

I installed Magento 2 on `Ubuntu/Apache/Sendmail` and setup email configuration on **Store -> Configuration -> Advanced System -> Mail Sending Settings & Sales -> Sales Email Settings**.
I configured cron via cli too.

Now, whenever an action takes place (example: Newaccount creation, new order or etc), the system is not sending email.

Please help me.

Comment: To increase the likelihood of your emails getting delivered to customers' inboxes, you could consider using an SMTP extension. eg  https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

Answer (score 0):

If you are on live server you need to enable sending emails and if you are on local server then you can achieve it by installing some Magento 2 extensions which are working perfectly.

Some of the tested extensions for custom SMTP are listed below:

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

First you need to send testing mail if it will work then you can go further and if this will not work then you need to debug like store id and area etc
do let me know if you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wasn't set hostname for my server. You can check hostname by typing just `hostname` in command line.

You can see current hostname then you can change hostname to a domain name as usual.

If you setup the domain name you are not using then, the mail propebly go to spam box.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to configure sendgrid extension. you could find more details here https://marketplace.magento.com/sendgrid-email-delivery-simplified.html